# 3d Canvas Frame on php

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I'm working on a project which is creating frame on run time but the
 owner wants difficult thing :) i managed to do some thing about this project.

> but the owner wants to like these :

[image: First thing]

> and

[image: second thing]

> **I found some codes on the internet which is this.**

```
        $im = new Imagick('Penguins.jpg');       
        $im->setImageFormat('png');
        $d = $im->getImageGeometry();
        $w = $d['width'];
        $h = $d['height'];
        $im3 = new Imagick();
        $im3->newImage(1, $h, 'none', 'png');
        $im3->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
        $im1 = $im->clone();

        $im1->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
        $im1->setImageMatte(true);
        $im1->cropImage(($w - 10), $h, 0, 0);
            /* $controlPoints = array(
             kenar açisi, orta açi,15,15,
            ($w - 10), 0, ($w - 10), 0,
            0, $h, 25, ($h - 20),
            ($w - 10), $h, ($w - 10), $h
        );*/
        $controlPoints = array(
             0,0,15,15,
            ($w - 10), 0, ($w - 10), 0,
            0, $h, 25, ($h - 20),
            ($w - 10), $h, ($w - 10), $h
        );
        $im1->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $controlPoints, true);
        $im2 = $im->clone();
        $im2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
        $im2->setImageMatte(true);          
        $im2->cropImage(10, $h, ($w - 10), 0);
        $controlPoints2 = array(
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            10, 0, 10, 10,
            0, $h, 0, $h,
            10, $h, 10, ($h - 10)
        );
        $im2->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $controlPoints2, true);

         $im4 = $im->clone();
        $im4->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
        $im4->setImageMatte(true);          
        $im4->cropImage($w, 10, 0,  0);
       $controlPoints4 = array(
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            10, 0, 10, 10,
            $w, 10, $w, 10,
            $w, 10, ($w -10 ), 10
        );
        $im4->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $controlPoints4, true);

        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->addImage($im4);
        $image->addImage($im1);
        $image->addImage($im3);
        $image->addImage($im2);
        $image->resetIterator();
        $combined = $image->appendImages(false);
        $shadow = $combined->clone();
        $shadow->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('black'));
        $shadow->shadowImage(50, 3, 5, 5);
        $shadow->compositeImage($combined, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);    
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        echo $shadow;
```

> And Result :

[image]

> Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would guess you could crop the image and work on each part seperatly. One problem you will have as with a lot of other effects people want is there will need to be some if not a lot of user input as the images are different heights. I did try some code which worked on areas of interest but I can not find it now.

Comment: So what have you tried so far and what is your *concrete* problem you run into? As long as your problem is only that you didn't found a fitting chunk of code online, we can't do much about it, you need to search harder or start to code your own. But if you start your own (modification) you might be able to formulate an actual question that can be answered. I appreciate if you update your question accordingly (it already looks great with the pictures, however the problem is pretty broad).

Comment: You know, you could get quite close to this with css3..

Comment: Have a look at the google play homepage, they did something which is similar with the rotating triangles there.

Comment: you are right But it is so difficult maybe someone did it.i found some website which do the same thing.
like this site http://www.pluscanvas.com/tablonu-sen-tasarla.html

Comment: the owner doesnt want :( @danp

Comment: @TacettinÖzbölük: Tell your owner to join here so we can discuss the details ;)

Comment: Thinking more about this it would be possible. You would need to make the canvas effect into a function or class. When you get the original photo the user whould need to decide on the format they want the picture say 3 or 5 pieces. You then need to calculate the sizes for each piece and send it to the function. Personaly I do not like the result you have posted as I would be looking to see the top edge and there is a gap between the main image and the side piece. These could be overcome with some code changes.

Comment: Yes I have to work earch of 16 pieces.it will be combined hardly =)) thanks a lot for your opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also a newbie in imagick and I believe we are working on same kind of project.

Here's my approach, but it needs to be improved.

```
$im = new Imagick('Koala.jpg');
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->cropThumbnailImage(300,200);

$p1 = $im->clone();
$p1->cropImage(50, 150, 0, 25);
$p1->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$p1->setImageMatte(true);

$cPoints = array(
    0,0, 5,5, 
    50,0, 50,0, 
    0,150, 5,145, 
    50,150, 50,150 
);

$p1->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $cPoints, true);

$p2 = $im->clone();
$p2->cropImage(5, 150, 50, 25);
$p2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$p2->setImageMatte(true);

$cPoints2 = array(
    0,0, 0,0, 
    5,0, 5,5, 
    0,150, 0,150, 
    5,150, 5,145 
);    

$p2->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $cPoints2, true);

$canvas1 = new Imagick();
$canvas1->newImage(55, 200, 'none','png');
$canvas1->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$canvas1->setImageMatte(true);

$canvas1->compositeImage( $p1, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0,25 );
$canvas1->compositeImage( $p2, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 50,25 );

$p3 = new Imagick();
$p3->newImage(10, 200, 'none','png');
$p3->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

$p4 = $im->clone();
$p4->cropImage(50, 200, 65, 0);
$p4->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$p4->setImageMatte(true);

$cPoints4 = array(
    0,0, 5,5, 
    50,0, 50,0, 
    0,200, 5,195, 
    50,200, 50,200 
);

$p4->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $cPoints4, true);

$p5 = $im->clone();
$p5->cropImage(5, 200, 135, 0);
$p5->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$p5->setImageMatte(true);

$cPoints5 = array(
    0,0, 0,0, 
    5,0, 5,5, 
    0,200, 0,200, 
    5,200, 5,195 
);

$p5->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $cPoints5, true);

$p6 = new Imagick();
$p6->newImage(10, 200, 'none','png');
$p6->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

$p7 = $im->clone();
$p7->cropImage(50, 150, 150, 25);
$p7->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$p7->setImageMatte(true);

$cPoints7 = array(
    0,0, 5,5, 
    50,0, 50,0, 
    0,150, 5,145, 
    50,150, 50,150 
);

$p7->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $cPoints7, true);

$p8 = $im->clone();
$p8->cropImage(5, 150, 200, 25);
$p8->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$p8->setImageMatte(true);

$cPoints8 = array(
    0,0, 0,0, 
    5,0, 5,5, 
    0,150, 0,150, 
    5,150, 5,145 
);

$p8->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $cPoints8, true);

$canvas2 = new Imagick();
$canvas2->newImage(55, 200, 'none','png');
$canvas2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$canvas2->setImageMatte(true);

$canvas2->compositeImage( $p7, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0,25 );
$canvas2->compositeImage( $p8, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 50,25 );

$pImage = new Imagick();
$pImage->addImage($canvas1);
$pImage->addImage($p3);
$pImage->addImage($p4);
$pImage->addImage($p5);
$pImage->addImage($p6);
$pImage->addImage($canvas2);
$pImage->resetIterator();

$combined = $pImage->appendImages(false);

$shadow = $combined->clone(); 

$shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) ); 

$shadow->shadowImage( 50, 3, 5, 5 ); 


$shadow->compositeImage( $combined, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 ); 

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $shadow;
```

and the result is;

[image]

I hope it helps
but please let us know if you find an easier solution because I need it too :)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me avoid hours worth of fruitless search.